# iframe src disappearing after lightbox is closed then re-opend

Tags: wordpress, iframe, youtube, lightbox

I'm working on this WordPress site http://rgpfamtour.digital-55.com/ and am trying to figure out why the iframe `src` is disappearing after exiting out of the lightbox  that appears when clicking "Watch Trailer".

When the button is first click, the video in the iframe loads fine. However, when exiting out of the lightbox and then clicking "Watch Trailer" again, the video does not load, and the YouTube iframe `src` element reads "unknown".

I've tried disabling plugins and using different YouTube embed plugins and just manually embedding the iframe HTML, but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: What modal plugin you using? I would assume, that it is removing the source based upon a jQuery function that is fired when that modal closes.

Comment: The modal plugin is built into the theme.

Comment: Well it is definitely the modal javascript. Can you look through the js files for the modal? You will be looking for a click event on ".close-btn" more than likely